# Rails 5 - what is the correct way to access this model structure from a single entity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I have a Product and Category model structure, however, the attributes that belong to each product are dependent upon which category they are in.

Please note that this is not about STI (single table inheritance) as I am not implementing specific classes that inherit from `Product` (eg like `Book < Product`, `Bicycle < Product` etc)

I have the following model classes (simplified to the pertinent code only):

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  # Relationships
  belongs_to :subcategory
  delegate :category, to: :subcategory, allow_nil: true
  has_many :product_category_attributes
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  # Relationships
  has_many :subcategories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, through: :subcategories
  has_many :category_attributes, dependent: :destroy
end

class CategoryAttribute < ApplicationRecord
  # Relationships
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :product_category_attributes, dependent: :destroy
end

class ProductCategoryAttribute < ApplicationRecord
  # Relationships
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category_attribute
end
```

This works but...bear with me here!

Here is the migrations for the category hierarchy:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :categories, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateCategoryAttributes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :category_attributes, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.references :category, type: :uuid, foreign_key: true, index: true 
      t.string :name
      t.string :value
      
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateProductCategoryAttributes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :product_category_attributes, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.references :product, type: :uuid, foreign_key: true
      t.references :category_attribute, type: :uuid, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :product_category_attributes, [:product_id, :category_attribute_id], unique: true, name: 'index_product_category_attributes_on_fks'
  end
end
```

Imagine a category with the name 'Rugs'. Rugs have a size, so:

`category_attribute.name` would be 'size'

and

`category_attribute.values` would have 3 - 'small', 'medium', 'large'

So in the `category_attribute' table:

| id | name | value

| 1  | size | small

| 2  | size | medium

| 3  | size | large

But an individual Rug product might only be available in 'small'.

So that's the reason for the `ProductCategoryAttribute` -> I can assign only the attributes that applies to that particular product.

What I don't understand is how can I 'short-cut' the ActiveRecord associations created.

For example, if I load a `Product` in memory, how can I modify the associations so that I can do:

`product.category_attributes` or even
`product.attributes`

to return only those applicable to that product.

As an example, I know I can get a single attribute like this:

`p.product_category_attributes.first.category_attribute`

and that obviously only returns the first one (and is also quite unwieldy).

I believe there is a way to add a method or a scope - I'd like to call it 'attributes' - that could solve my problem, but I am a bit lost on how to proceed.

It seems that `attributes` is already reserved by ActiveModel?

**Attempt 1**
Barking up the wrong tree here but worth a try, eh?

Product.rb

```
  def cat_attributes
    self.product_category_attributes.each do |pca|
      return pca.category_attribute
    end
  end
```

Returns the `product_category_attributes`, not the `category_attributes`

**Attempt 2**

Product.rb

```
has_many :category_attributes, through: :product_category_attributes
```

This returns the data I want, but now how do I alias the name to something shorter?

**Attempt 3**

Product.rb

```
has_many :cat_atts, class_name: 'CategoryAttribute', through: :product_category_attributes, source: :category_attributes
```

**Attempt 4**

```
Delete *.*
ReturnTo C#
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-one-source) you can go with your attempt 3 version. Like:

```
# app/models/product.rb

  has_many :product_category_attributes
  has_many :cat_atts, through: :product_category_attributes, source: :category_attribute
```

Comment: Ha you just beat me to my attempt 5, which was the same as your answer! Well done sir :)

Comment: I have just modified a little bit. Your `source` declaration was wrong. Thanks, Happy to help you!